# OpenCV video processin int iOS change camera

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I have a question about OpenCV video processing and iOS.
I followed this tutorial to create a simple example project.
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#basic-video-processing

```
self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 60;
self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = YES;

self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;

self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
```

It works well but I can't change to use the back camera.
I use this line to change the camera but it not work:

```
self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these two commands:

```
[self.videoCamera setDesiredCameraPosition: AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
```

and if that doesn't work, try:

```
[self.videoCamera switchCameras];
```

and see if you have better luck.

Comment: [self.videoCamera setDesiredCameraPosition: AVCaptureDevicePositionBack] does not seem to exist. [self.videoCamera switchCameras] not change the camera

Comment: [self.videoCamera switchCameras]; 
Works great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have written the following line twice:

(self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];)

After the second call, all setting have lost.
Remove the second one, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using [self.videoCamera switchCameras];